# Wordpress site and Slashdot effect - what kind of hosting service (solution) do I need to search for?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, high-traffic

I admin Wordpress site with 120k Facebook fans. Site has 750,000 pageviews/month according to GA.

**When the owner shares something on site's FB fan page, my 4GB RAM VPS is immediately out of RAM and I see error 500 (service unavailable).** 99% of time it 4GB sufficiently enough. This is known as [Slashdot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect).

Is there any webhosting service which solves this problem. I don't want the name of specific webhosting company, **I want to know what kind of hosting service or solution I should google out.**

Does anybody from you experience with this? How did you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server that can handle the 1% not the 99%.

Likely you should be looking at a dedicated server with minimum 16Gb RAM, but you should take to the hosting service you are considering.  Tell them what you have, explain the problem and they should be able to advise.

Comment: Isn't there any VPS hosting solutions with flexible RAM or something like this. Rent extra RAM just when you need it?

Comment: There might be.  Check with VPS sellers

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be solved with caching, something like [Varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software)), etc. Lots of hosts implement something like this, Dreamhost I know does, I would start there.

Your server is consuming RAM because it is re-calculating the page each time there is a request. That's not good. If the request is the same as lots of other previous requests, you don't want to think about it and consume RAM, you want to send your cached copy that the server already has available. This is really fast.

Comment: Yeah, basically it's still same page, even comments are disabled. I found out that [WP Super cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin can "HTMLize" post pages and served them cached. Tnks for an answare.

Comment: [This](https://deliciousbrains.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-server-monitoring-caching/) is even better.